# Receiving File parameter in IBM Notes web-service provider

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-notes

I have a java web service provider, with String and File(.doc) parameters.
Please, help me to correctly receive the File parameter. How do I must declare it in inputs?

```
public String createOrder (String subject, String file){
  return "ok";
}
```

I try to test  by  SoapUI(sending .doc attachment), and I receive this error:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
    <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.</faultstring>
    <detail/>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok, i have corrected my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a `java.io.File` as input parameter in WS Provide. However, you could have a `byte[]` as parameter, which could be translated into a file. 
Please have a look at *Designer Help* and search for *Java and LotusScript mappings*. You'll find a whole bunch of data types for a WS Provider.